# expression 'a' is of type 'int' and has to be used (or discarded)

Tags: nim-lang

I'm trying to rewrite the cryptomath code from [here](https://github.com/TheAlgorithms/Python/blob/master/ciphers/cryptomath_module.py) and I'm getting this when I try to compile to JS;

```
Hint: used config file '/home/*******/.choosenim/toolchains/nim-1.6.8/config/nim.cfg' [Conf]
Hint: used config file '/home/*******/.choosenim/toolchains/nim-1.6.8/config/config.nims' [Conf]
...........................................................
/home/*******/nim/cryptomath.nim(6, 9) Error: expression 'a' is of type 'int' and has to be used (or discarded)
```

This is my code:

```
import std/random
import std/math
randomize()
proc gcd*(a: int, b: int): int = 
    while a != 0:
        a, b = floorMod(b,a), a # fails here apparently
    return (b+a)-a

proc find_mod_inverse*(a: int, m: int): int =
    if gcd(a,m) != 1:
        return -1
    var 
        u1 = 1
        u2 = 0
        u3 = a
        v1 = 0
        v2 = 1
        v3 = m
        q = -1

    while v3 != 0:
        q = floorDiv(u3,v3)
        v1 = (u1 - q * v1)
        v2 = (u2 - q * v2)
        v3 = (u3 - q * v3)
        u1 = v1
        u2 = v2
        u3 = v3
    return floorMod(u1,m)
```

I tried adding this, but it did nothing

```
discard a
```

before the end of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

- Function arguments in Nim are immutable by default, so if you want to overwrite them locally, you need to shadow them or use `var`
- Nim syntax for multiple variable assignment is different from Python and is done with tuple-like syntax

Fixed code would look like this:

```
import std/random
import std/math
randomize()
proc gcd*(a: int, b: int): int = 
    var (a, b) = (a, b)
    while a != 0:
        (a, b) = (floorMod(b,a), a)
    return (b+a)-a

proc find_mod_inverse*(a: int, m: int): int =
    if gcd(a,m) != 1:
        return -1
    var 
        u1 = 1
        u2 = 0
        u3 = a
        v1 = 0
        v2 = 1
        v3 = m
        q = -1

    while v3 != 0:
        q = floorDiv(u3,v3)
        v1 = (u1 - q * v1)
        v2 = (u2 - q * v2)
        v3 = (u3 - q * v3)
        u1 = v1
        u2 = v2
        u3 = v3
    return floorMod(u1,m)
```

The compiler error is unclear, I agree.

Also, just a tip - keep in mind that standard Nim integers are limited by the architecture's native integer size, so if you want to operate on big numbers, you need to use a separate library.